# Set default variable using directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looping through an array of objects using ng-repeat and printing it to a table in my view, but depending on what an api returns, I may not have a value for each attribute of each object. This results in a table with blank spaces.  I would like for the blanks to simply show "0" rather than just be empty.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this without adding "0" values to the objects?

e.g

```
var rooms = [
    {room_num:'1', seats_available:'5'},
    {room_num:'2', seats_available:'12'},
    {room_num:'3'}
]
```

view:

```
<div ng-repeat='room in rooms'>
  <h1>Room:{{room.room_num}}</h1>
  <h2>Seats:{{rom.seats_available}}</h2>
</div>
```

would result in a blank for seats available in room 3. I would like it to just show 0.

Comment: you could also use `<h2>Seats:{{rom.seats_available || "0"}}</h2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ternary operator.

```
<div ng-repeat='room in rooms'>
   <h1>Room:{{room.room_num}}</h1>
   <h2>Seats:{{room.seats_available ? room.seats_available : "0" }}</h2>
</div>
```

You could also just use `||`. Which will work the same. However I think it's not great convention to do so.

```
<div ng-repeat='room in rooms'>
   <h1>Room:{{room.room_num}}</h1>
   <h2>Seats:{{room.seats_available || "0" }}</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{room.seats_available || "0" }}
```

(Be careful with Boolean values thow)